# Relationship between thermal conductivity and reaching the steady temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

The diagram is for three materials with 3 different thermal conductivities, i think the material with higher thermal conductivity is the number 1 because it transfers the heat much better so it gets to the steady temperature sooner than the other two,am i correct? If not or if my reason isn't correct , i appreciate your helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must represent the average temperature, or the temperature at some specific location within the body (since the temperature will be a function of spatial location and time).  Just ask yourself what the curve would look like if the thermal conductivity of the material were zero.  This should give you your answer.

Comment: If k=0 then there is no heat transfer ,so the temperature remains constant and it wont reach that avg temperature,right? So the material with highest conductivity reaches that temperature faster?

Comment: Sure.  This is how you can  "bound the answer" to address your question.